# jQuery datepicker not working on click

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my datepicker show up when this button is pressed. I don't see what's wrong with my code, to me, it should work.. but it's not. Could someone take a look? (sorry, new to jQuery and code in general).

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<button id="datepicker" class="btn btn-light">Jump to a specific date</button>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field.

You can show datepicker on a button with the below code.

```js
$( function() {

$("#dateButton").datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  buttonText: 'Jump to a specific date',
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  constrainInput: true
});

  } );
```

```css
#dateButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input id="dateButton" class="btn btn-light" />
```

Comment: This also looks like a great method, but it's saying datepicker not a function, even though I literally copy and pasted the code above. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: yes this: " TypeError: $("#datepicker").datepicker is not a function. (In '$("#datepicker").datepicker()', '$("#datepicker").datepicker' is undefined) "

Comment: Its because I dont have #datepicker I used #dateButton

Comment: Now it's: TypeError: $("#dateButton").datepicker is not a function. (In '$("#dateButton").datepicker({
  showOn: 'button',
  buttonText: 'Jump to a specific date',
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  constrainInput: true
})', '$("#dateButton").datepicker' is undefined). If it helps, I've made the page live here: http://test-checker.com/booking-test.html - I'm probably doing something stupid.

Comment: @MattH You are loading jQuery 2 times, one at top and one above body closing. Remove from top, and jquery-ui.js should load on after jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170688/discussion-between-kiranvj-and-matt-h).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170757/discussion-between-kiran-paul-vj-and-matt-h).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the datepicker should be instantiated on an `input` element, so that the value selected has somewhere to be stored (ie. in the value of that input).

Then you can use the `show` option of the datepicker to display it when the button is clicked, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show')
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="datepicker" name="date" />
<button class="btn btn-light">Jump to a specific date</button>
```

Comment: This seems like a very simple approach, makes sense. I'm having a problem working it though (may be my fault as your code appears to be working). With me, it says "datepickers not a function" any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Check to ensure you've included jquery-ui.js in the page.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one. you forget to put cdn of datetime picker css and js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="datepicker" class="btn btn-light">Jump to a specific date</button>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });    
</script>
```

Comment: OP is using the jQueryUI datepicker (which was already included in the page correctly) not the Bootstrap one